# JAX-WS servlet filter exceptions

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, jax-ws, servlet-filters

I have a client/server application that communicates via SOAP.  The server-side application is a Java EE app that exposes web services using JAX-WS.  I have a servlet filter setup to perform certain checks before a service is invoked.

This is all working pretty well, except for exception handling.  If I throw an exception from the filter, it gets returned to the client as a generic server exception.  I need to find a way to propagate a custom exception containing a specific message, so the client can display the message to the user.

Any insight?

Answer (score 8):

A servlet filter isn't really the right tool if you want to send the exception in a SOAP  response and I would consider using a JAX-WS handler for the verification of incoming messages instead (JAX-WS handlers are somehow to JAX-WS services what Filters are to Servlets).

Frmo [Working with Headers in JAX-WS SOAPHandlers](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/post/Working-with-Headers-in-JAX-WS-SOAPHandlers.aspx):

> #### [JAX-WS Handlers](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/post/Working-with-Headers-in-JAX-WS-SOAPHandlers.aspx)
>
> In addition to support for web
>   services development, the JAX-WS
>   framework (the latest Java programming
>   language API for creating SOAP-based
>   web services and web service
>   consumers) also provides a handler
>   framework.  Handlers provide a means
>   to inspect and manipulate incoming or
>   outgoing SOAP messages (on both the
>   client as well as server side).  They
>   act as powerful message interceptors
>   that can perform an array of functions
>   such as message transformation,
>   content filtering, tracking, etc.  In
>   fact, handlers are often used in
>   runtime environments to implement web
>   service and SOAP specifications such
>   as WS-Security, WS-ReliableMessaging,
>   etc.  JAX-WS handlers are similar to
>   EJB interceptors or servlet filters. 
>   Handlers, like interceptors and
>   filters, encourage developers to
>   follow the chain of responsibility
>   pattern.

#### Resources

- [Writing a Handler in JAX-WS](http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/java-api-for-xml-web-services/writing-a-handler-in-jax-ws.html) (start here)
- [Handler example using JAXWS 2.0](http://blogs.oracle.com/sdimilla/entry/implementing_handlers_using_jaxws_2)

#### References

- [Java API for XML-Based Web Services (JAX-WS) 2.0 specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=224)
- APIs

  - [`javax.xml.ws.handler.Handler`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/Handler.html)
  - [`javax.xml.ws.handler.LogicalHandler`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/LogicalHandler.html)
  - [`javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/soap/SOAPHandler.html)

Comment: Right, he was after all using the wrong tools. That clears up everything.

Comment: @BalusC At least, I think so.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm going to try this out.