# Error 404 when I add @RequestScoped to the @WebService

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish, osgi

I use OSGI and I created web-service. My App server is Glassfish 3. Java 1.7

```
@WebService(name="MyService", serviceName = "MyWebServices")
public interface IMyService 
{
//some code
}

@Stateless(name = "MyService")
@HandlerChain(file = "handler-chain.xml")
@WebService(serviceName = "MyWebServices", endpointInterface="com.examlple.webservices.IMyService")
public class MyService implements IMyService 
{
//some code
}
```

My service works! And I want to add Servlet Filter. I found answer in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702793/is-it-possible-to-define-a-servlet-filter-for-a-stateless-ejb-webservice-on-gla) that I should add @RequestScoped annotation to my service implementation.

```
@Stateless(name = "MyService")
@HandlerChain(file = "handler-chain.xml")
@WebService(serviceName = "MyWebServices", endpointInterface="com.examlple.webservices.IMyService")
@RequestScoped
public class MyService implements IMyService 
{
//some code
}
```

But after that I've got error 404 in responses. I cannot find the reason of this bug.

Comment: Can't you try the @postConstruct or @Interceptor(..) annonations as mentioned in the thread?

Answer (score 0):

I guess a ServletFilter is the wrong tool here because you don't have a servlet. It looks like what you need is a [SoapHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/soap/SOAPHandler.html).

Here is an example how it could look like:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;

public class MyServiceLogHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext arg0) {
        SOAPMessage message= arg0.getMessage();
        try {
            message.writeTo(System.out);
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext arg0) {
        SOAPMessage message= arg0.getMessage();
        boolean isOutboundMessage=  (Boolean)arg0.get (MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
        if(isOutboundMessage){
            System.out.println("OUTBOUND MESSAGE\n");

        }else{
            System.out.println("INBOUND MESSAGE\n");
        }
        try {
            message.writeTo(System.out);
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**See also:**

- [Creating and Using SOAP Message Handlers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv_adv/handlers.html)
- [JAX-WS servlet filter exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566975/jax-ws-servlet-filter-exceptions)

Comment: Can I interrapt request like `http://localhost/MyWebServices/MyService?WSDL` using SOAPHandler?

Comment: Sorry, I mean "intercept"

Comment: Sorry, soaphandler intercepts soap messages but not request like `http://localhost/MyWebServices/MyService?WSDL`